# Displaying code-generated textures in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, rust, glfw

I want to provide canvas API based on OpenGL in Rust, so I decided to serve a single rectangle in OpenGL and update its texture. I created a texture of red line and it isn't displaying as I expected.

How I generate the texture:

```rust
let mut texture = 0;
gl::GenTextures(1, &mut texture);
gl::BindTexture(gl::TEXTURE_2D, texture); // all upcoming GL_TEXTURE_2D operations now have effect on this texture object
                                          // set the texture wrapping parameters
gl::TexParameteri(gl::TEXTURE_2D, gl::TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl::REPEAT as i32); // set texture wrapping to gl::REPEAT (default wrapping method)
gl::TexParameteri(gl::TEXTURE_2D, gl::TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl::REPEAT as i32);
// set texture filtering parameters
gl::TexParameteri(gl::TEXTURE_2D, gl::TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl::NEAREST as i32);
gl::TexParameteri(gl::TEXTURE_2D, gl::TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl::NEAREST as i32);
// load image, create texture and generate mipmaps

let mut data_ = [(0, 0, 0); 512 * 512];
gl::TexImage2D(
    gl::TEXTURE_2D,
    0,
    gl::RGB as i32,
    512,
    512,
    0,
    gl::RGB,
    gl::UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    &data_[0] as *const _ as *const c_void,
);

for i in 0..512 {
    data_[i + 512 * i] = (255, 0, 0);
}
gl::TexSubImage2D(
    gl::TEXTURE_2D,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    512,
    512,
    gl::RGB,
    gl::UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    &data_[0] as *const _ as *const c_void,
);
```

How I display it:

```
// bind Texture
gl::BindTexture(gl::TEXTURE_2D, texture);

// render container
ourShader.useProgram();
gl::BindVertexArray(VAO);
gl::DrawElements(gl::TRIANGLES, 6, gl::UNSIGNED_INT, ptr::null());
```

Vertex shader:

```c
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    ourColor = aColor;
    TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(texture1, TexCoord);
}
```

And I get:

[image: Given image].

I expected pixels to touch each other. Size of the window: 512x512, size of the texture: 512x512. Also, I tried linear tex filtering, but still the same.

Comment: Tuples do not have a defined layout, so giving a pointer to tuples to OpenGL might be risky: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#tuple-layout
I'm not sure this has anything to do with your problem, but maybe try a flat array instead.

Comment: Well, I could imagine a few ways to achieve the effect that you seem to have gotten in OpenGL, but they all would more or less deliberately create such an effect, not really by accident. Are your sure your actual input data does contain a correctly rasterized line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't specify the type of the `data_` array. It seems that Rust deduces its type to be a 32-bit integer, whereas you told OpenGL that your data contains **unsigned bytes**. This discrepancy causes your red pixels to appear only every fourth row. Sorry I don't know Rust, so can't say how to specify the type of the array.

Comment: `let mut data_: [(u32, u32, u32); 512 * 512]  = [(0, 0, 0); 512 * 512];` or `let mut data_ = [(0u32, 0u32, 0u32); 512 * 512];`

Comment: And, as mentioned in a [comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61170901/displaying-code-generated-textures-in-opengl#comment108215335_61170901), tuples don't have a defined layout, so that's yet another avenue for this to break.

Comment: @Shepmaster: shouldn't that be `(u8,u8,u8)`?

Comment: Oh, I only read as far as "unsigned" and skipped "bytes" . Yes. With the tuple comment, it's probably better as `[[u8; 3]; 512 * 512]`.